# Using argparse, how do I send an argument from inside the same file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

For example:

```
def main(i):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    ## Required parameters
    parser.add_argument("--data_dir", default='data/text', type=str,
                    help="The input data dir. Should contain the .tsv files (or other data files) for the task.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.data_dir) #This outputs the default 'data/text' even though I've specified it to be data/non

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    results = main(['--data_dir', 'data/non'])
```

I tried the example above. However, it outputs the default 'data/text' even though I've specified it to be 'data/non'. Is there a way for me to be able to call argparse from the same python file? Preferably, I can do more than one argument too. Thanks.

This is Python 3.10

Comment: You need to pass `i` to `parser.parse_args`,  as [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args).

Comment: I'd suggest: don't. Use argparse to parse what's coming from the command line, by all means, but once you have that namespace object you can interact with it much more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_args` parses by default `sys.argv[1:]`. If you want to parse something else, for instance in your case `i` you will need to call `parse_args` with `i` -

`parser.parse_args(i)`

(p.s I recommend using a more informative name than `i`)

Comment: Thank you! This indeed helped with me being able to pass the arguments in.

Answer (score 1):

Functions like

```
def parse(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ....
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args
```

are common.  If `argv` is `None`, either as called or with the default, then `sys.argv[1:]`, from the commandline, is used.  Otherwise the programmer can call the function as you do, most often for testing purposes, or with some customization of the `sys.argv`.

```
results = parse(['--data_dir', 'data/non'])
```

or

```
results = parse()
```